# JavaFX how to make text underlined in textarea?

Tags: java, javafx

I tried:

```
    .hyperlink-text-area .content,
    .hyperlink-text-area {
        -fx-underline: true;
    }
```

But it not worked.
I'm not sure now that texarea supports the underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fx-underline` property is a property of [`Text` nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text), so you have to apply it to the text node belonging to the text area. Assuming the `.hyperlink-text-area` selector selects a `TextArea` (or other `TextInputControl`), you can do

```css
.hyperlink-text-area .text {
    -fx-underline: true ;
}
```